# .AddEventListner is not a fuction

Tags: javascript, html, dom, responsive

guys. Im trying to show/hide a mobile menu on click, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. If  you may help me, I'd be really thankful:

```
   <script>
    var menuToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('menuToggle');
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('responsive-navigation');
    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (nav === 'block') {
            nav.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            nav.style.display = "block";

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: .AddEventListner is not a fuction for **menuToggle**, because menuToggle is an **array collection**

Comment: there's a dupe somewhere, just can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns collection. You have to use specific *index*. I think you also mistakenly comparing the element itself to the property value in the *if* condition.

Though I prefer using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method `querySelector()` ***returns the first Element*** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned

```
var menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuToggle');
var nav = document.querySelector('.responsive-navigation');
menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (nav.style.display === 'block') {
    nav.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, guys, now the problem I have, is that , it won;t hide the the container for the Menu, cna you help me with that, too, and thank you, a lot for your help

Comment: `nav` will **never** equal the string `"block"`

Comment: @JesúsBohorquez, as Phil mentioned in his comment, you should check the value of the display property not the element itself. Please check the updated answer....

Comment: it did, thank you a lot